# How can I draw this matrix in Latex?

Tags: matrices, psmatrix

[image]

I want to draw this matrix in Latex and this is what I was trying to do but it doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it to make it look like the attached picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,intlimits,tbtags,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\label{my-label}
$A_{n} = \left( 
\begin{array}{l|c|c}
2\hspace{2 em}9 & 2
& \\
1\hspace{2 em}2 & 5\hspace{2 em}2 & \\ \cline{1-3}

\hspace{2 em}3 & 7\hspace{2 em}5\hspace{2 em}2&  & \\ 
\hspace{2 em}&3\hspace{2 em}7\hspace{2 em}5\hspace{2 em}2&  \\\cline{1-3}

 &   3&1\hspace{2 em}9  &\\
 
 &   &5\hspace{2 em}4 \\ 
    

\end{array}
\right)$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many possibilities to draw that matrix, one of them could be using `nicematrix` package. If you see the manual, in page 3 you will find an example very similar to your image

Comment: What manual are you talking about? please i do not understand where i have to look, can be more specified where i can found this manual? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write `texdoc nicematrix` in a command line or search in ctan. After doing the last one here is the link for the manual https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix

Comment: ok, i will do that, thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have your matrix within a table.  How about this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A_{n} = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc|cccccc|cc}
    2 & 9 & 2 &&&&&&&\\
    1 & 2 & 5 & 2&&&&&&\\
    \hline
    & 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 &&&&&\\
    && 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 &&&&\\
    &&& 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 &&&\\
    &&&& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &&\\
    &&&&&& 3 & 7 & 5 & 2\\
    \hline
    &&&&&&& 3 & 1 & 9\\
    &&&&&&&& 5 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are Genius! Thank you so so much, I've been trying to write it for two days and I can't and I gave up but now you saved me. And I don't know about the table either, why it should be a table considering that it is a Toeplitz matrix that can be written without a table, but I think it's written that way to separate the numbers so that it can be seen better, I don't see another explanation .

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: Why `\hline{}`? The braces serve no purpose and in other contexts they might be dangerous: try `\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ \hline{} \multicolumn{2}{c}{123} \end{array}`

Comment: Good choice using `\cdots`.  This looks better than the original.

Comment: Yes, you can drop the `{}`.  Would there be a instance where you would need the curly braces to get the right spacing?  If it is a bad idea, why did you put `{}` after your `\hline`? @egreg

Comment: @mcarchmiller I put `{}` to show that an error may ensue if they're used.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code above

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,intlimits,tbtags,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\label{my-label}
$A_{n} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc|*{6}{c}|cc}
 2 & 9 & 2 & & & & & \\
 1 & 2 & 5 & 2 & & & & \\ \hline
 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 & & & \\
 & & 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 & & \\
 & & & 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 & \\
 & & & & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}|}{\dotfill} & \\%
 & & & & & & 3 & 7 & 5 & 2 \\ \hline
 & & & & & & & 3 & 1 & 9 \\
 & & & & & & & & 5 & 4
\end{array}
\right)$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]